# Navigation between pages bottom nav-bar flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, bottomnavigationview, flutter-pageview, flutter-bottomnavigation

[image]I am using flutter. I would like to navigate between pages of bottom nav-bar from inside the body of page.
Not to create a new screen on top of it. And carry data between pages.
I am using classic bottom navbar in flutter with pages in body of scaffold.

Something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried pageview but with that I can switch between pages only on swipe and cant send data between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also get that widget from other places with A `GlobalKey` :

First, create a `GlobalKey` in the global scope ( make it outside you `StatefulWidegt` class )

```
final glbKey = GlobalKey();
```

then assign that key to `BottomNavigationBar` :

```
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          key: glbKey,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
   // ...
```

Now, you can call it from your `onPressed` method like this:

```
   onPressed: () {
     //...
     BottomNavigationBar navigationBar = glbKey.currentWidget as BottomNavigationBar;
     navigationBar.onTap!(2); // change 2 with index of your target screen

       }
```

Comment: Navigation part worked thanks. But is there a way to send data(TEXT example in image) also.

Comment: Glad that helped, yes there is, you can simply create a global scope variable or a custom class that saves the data with a static type inside that onTap method, then use it when you need it on your app.

Comment: It did work, I figured out that I can do it with class so I didn't check your answer immediately. Using global scope variable also works. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply simulate running the `_onItemTapped()` with the index of your target navigation item, in your search button icon `onPressed`, add this:

```
onPressed: () {
//...
_onItemTapped(2); // replace 2 with you screen index.
}
```

this will navigate to the search page programmatically.

Comment: My onPressed in inside  body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ), so I have no access to onItemTapped(); inside child.

Comment: check my other answer!